# TypeInitializationException on form.show, where it used to work

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've been working on a program for the past month, pretty simple, but it have to load multiple forms, especially since there is a launcher.
Everything worked well till this morning, where I accenttally pressed "Yes" when a Pop-up asked me something I didn't have time to read.

Since then, I've been getting

> TypeInitializationException

and

> NullReferenceException

When opening `Form2` from `Form1`

```vb
Form2.Variable = Form1.Textbox.Text
Form2.Show()
```

Comment: Some precisions for future references :
Form2 was missing a dll (After a Visual Studio update it would seems ? Or maybe some missclick) causing an intern NullReferenceException when creating variables on load, that was translated as both `TypeInitializationException` and `NullReferenceException`when trying to load the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeInitializationException (the exception that you are seeing) is thrown whenever a static constructor throws an exception, or whenever you attempt to access a class where the static constructor threw an exception.

With the NullReferenceException you are probably trying to use something that is null (or Nothing in VB.NET). This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all.

Like anything else, null gets passed around. If it is null in method "A", it could be that method "B" passed a null to method "A". - taken from this [brilliant answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

If you post more code or that I could potentially see whats wrong but good placce to start is setting any vairbales to `nothing` and also checking any dll you insert are still there etc.

`string foo = null;
foo.ToUpper()` would cause a nullexception so maybe it's occuring when the textbox is empty?

Comment: Thanks, I now know where to look ! 
There isn't much more code. I'll try removing the Form2.Load() event and edit my post.
The Texbox isn't empty, it's pretty much a "login" system (Except there isn't any real login system at the moment)

Comment: I removed the Load event on Form2 AND `Form2.Variable = Form1.Textbox.Text` and nothing change. However, `Form3.Show()` seems to work just fine

Comment: no problem @Thryn! Hope you find your answer. https://www.thegeeksclub.com/vbnet-tutorial-22-coding-simple-login-form/ is a nice simple login form to begin with in terms of using 2 forms etc. if interested!

Comment: I am interested :) Thanks !

Comment: hm hard to tell without seeing all program, are you creating the instance of form2?

Comment: I am not creating a special instance. I tried looking into my code, I think a missing dll is causing this, as you said

Comment: So have your `form2` then wherever in your `form1` have something such as `Dim loggedInAs New Form2
        loggedIn.Show()`

Comment: Perfect, hopefully that is the issue and it fixes your problem, if so if you don't mind accepting the answer,if not i'll be here to help as much as I can!